# Running functional tests on firebase

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, android-uiautomator, firebase-test-lab

I will want to run a functional tests on firebase on various devices. Does firebase support functional testing in android?

Their testlab has three types of tests:

1. Robo test
2. Instrumentation test
3. Gameloop

Robo test is ruled out as it is just a stress test and a load test like a money runner

When it comes to instrumentation test, first thing I want to be clear on whether it is a functional test written in `expresso, UIautomator and ranorex?`

If yes, I see that I have to upload two `.apk's` in there, one is `AppApk` and `TestApk`. I would like to know if `AppApk` is the application under test and `TestApk` is the apk that is created to test the application?

If yes, I found uiautomator tests are bundled inside the `src` folder and is a java file. I also found that, there is a python wrapper for uiautomator that can be coded to write tests for android.

Now there is `kivy.org` to bundle python file into an `.apk` since android studio does not support python.

Now, How do i run Android uiautomator tests in python? Is there a way, to run python scripts inside the android studio?

And How to run functional tests in firebase? Do they support?

Comment: You're asking a lot of different questions here, and most of them are best addressed through other firebase support channels, such as the firebase-talk google group or direct product support.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not product support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: To run uiautomator tests written in python you can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) or [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/).